# Proof in ring homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory

I am looking at the solution one my teacher gave me to prove that a function $\phi$ from a ring R to a another ring S is a ring homomorphism.

He checks:

$$\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y) \\ \phi(x\star y) = \phi(x) \star \phi(y) \\ \phi(1_R) = 1_S$$

for any $x,y \in R$ and $1_R, 1_S$ the multiplicative identities in R and s respectively.

Is the third check really necessary?
It looks to me, that if we assume existence of identities in R and S (unitary rings) then it is included in the second condition. Or is it more subtle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not require $\phi(1)=1$, the zero map will be a ring homomorphism. This is not what one wants to have in the category of rings with unity.

Comment: Thank you, it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The third condition is mainly to avoid the zero map as an homomorphism.

To deduce the third condition from the second one, you most probably need to assume surjectivity and that $S$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: Surjectivity is enough, since the image of the unit will be a unit for the image.

Comment: Another sufficient condition would be that $S$ contains no non-trivial idempotents (for instance a domain) and that $\phi \neq 0$.